# How to do arithmetic operations on pixels in Java

Tags: java, pixel, bufferedimage

I have to add some constant value to all pixels in my image - for gray image and colored. But I don't know how can I do that. I read image by BufferedImage, and I'm trying to get 2d array of pixels.
I found something like BufferedImage.getRGB() but it returns weird values (negative and huge). How to add some value to my bufferedimage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

To get a `byte[]` of all pixels in the image and then loop over the `byte[]` adding your constant to each byte element.

If you want the bytes converted to a 2-dimensional byte[], I found an example that does just that ([Get Two Dimensional Pixel Array](https://sites.google.com/site/osdevlab/learn-java/image-processing/gettwodimensionalpixelarray)) .

In summary the code looks like:

```
private static int[][] convertToArrayLocation(BufferedImage inputImage) {
   final byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) inputImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData(); // get pixel value as single array from buffered Image
   final int width = inputImage.getWidth(); //get image width value
   final int height = inputImage.getHeight(); //get image height value
   int[][] result = new int[height][width]; //Initialize the array with height and width

    //this loop allocates pixels value to two dimensional array
    for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel++) {
       int argb = 0;
       argb = (int) pixels[pixel];

       if (argb < 0) { //if pixel value is negative, change to positive 
          argb += 256;
       }

       result[row][col] = argb;
       col++;

       if (col == width) {
          col = 0;
          row++;
       }
   }

   return result; //return the result as two dimensional array
} //!end of method!//
```

Comment: Is it any way to do it with 2d array? I have that requirement to use int[][] array.

Answer (score 0):

To add a constant value to all pixels, you can use [RescaleOp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html). Your constant will be the `offset` for each channel. Leave `scale` at `1.0` and `hints` may be `null`.

```
// Positive offset makes the image brighter, negative values makes it darker
int offset = 100; // ...or whatever your constant value is
BufferedImage brighter = new RescaleOp(1, offset, null)
                                 .filter(image, null);
```

To change the current image, instead of creating a new one, you may use:

```
new RescaleOp(1, offset, null)
        .filter(image, image);
```